# How to parse "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z" in Django Template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-haystack, solr4

In my Django html template, I get my SOLR facet_date result using haystack in the format 
"2015-01-01T00:00:00Z". How can I parse it in format "01/01/2015" in my template?
My template is

```
{{ facets.dates.created.start }}
```

What "|date:" option should I add to my template?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your date is a ISO string instead of a Python datetime.datetime, I guess you will have to parse it on the view or write a custom filter:

```
# yourapp/templatetags/parse_iso.py
from django.template import Library
import datetime

register = Library()

@register.filter(expects_localtime=True)
def parse_iso(value):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Then at the template:

```
{% load parse_iso %}

{{ value|parse_iso|date:'d/m/Y'}}
```

[edit]

> got this error `Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /search/ Exception Value: 'parse_iso' is not a valid tag library: Template library parse_iso not found`

Make sure you follow the [code layout prescribed in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout):

```
yourapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    ...
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        parse_iso.py
    views.py
```

Your country may use `m/d/Y` (`01/01/2015` is ambiguous, I suggest using an example like `31/01/2015` so it is clear if the first number represents day or month).

Comment: got this error `Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /search/
Exception Value: 'parse_iso' is not a valid tag library: Template library parse_iso not found`

Comment: Please follow the directory [layout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) described in Django docs: make sure `templatetags` is a python module inside your app containing a file named `__init__.py` (may be empty) along with `parse_iso.py`.

Comment: Great answer. Though instead of `.strptime()` to manually formatting the string, it is better to use `.fromisoformat()`.

Answer (score 4):

If `{{ facets.dates.created.start }}` is a datetime object then you can use

```
{{ facets.dates.created.start|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}
```

In case you are providing a string you can create a template filter to convert the string to datetime object and apply the `date` filter

```
@register.filter
def stringformat(value, args):
    return datetime.strptime(value, args)
```

In the template:

```
{{ facets.dates.created.start|stringformat:"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Django template tags for this. You need to use {{my_date|date:"some_format"}} which takes "my_date" as the argument (it should be a date object) to "date" tag and then formats it based on the given format.

```
{{facets.dates.created.start|date:"d/m/Y"}}
```

Comment: I tried this, but does not work. When I just do `{{ facets.dates.created.star }}`, 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z will be shown. But when I add `date:"d/m/Y"`, nothing shows when I load the template.

Comment: Please include some text explaining why you think this might solve the OP's problem.  Help others to understand.